# Finding a set $V$ such that for the corresponding vertex scheme $(V,\mathcal{S})$ there is a homeomorphism $|V|_{\mathcal{S}}\cong S^5$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $(V,\leq)$ be a partially ordered set. It determines a vertex scheme by the following construction: A nonempty finite subset $T\subset V$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}$ iff $T$ is totally ordered by the induced relation on $T$.

I am looking for a partially ordered set $(V,\leq)$ such that for the corresponding vertex scheme $(V,\mathcal{S})$, there exists a homeomorphism $|V|_{\mathcal{S}}\cong S^5=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^6\mid ||x||=1\}$.
The simplicial complex determined by a vertex scheme $(V, \mathcal{S})$ is a topological space $X =
|V|_{\mathcal{S}}$ . We describe it first as a set. An element of $X$ is a function $f:V\to [0,1]$ such that $\sum_{v\in V}f(v)=1$
and the set $\{v\in V\mid f(v)>0\}$ is an element of $\mathcal{S}$.

Also, kindly establish the homeomorphism mathematically.

Comment: You’ll want to be clear about what $|V|_{\mathcal S}$ and $S^5$ mean.

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I have added the respective definitions.